# Is it Possible To Copy Files PHP via Post Method

Tags: php, path, copy, directory, dir

im trying to copy selected files form within a form table to a new folder in php.. For some reason I cant seem to figure out why my code isn't working appropriately. Is there a way to do this via POST method..I basically want to only copy files if there is a file selected from the form table via Post Method. A snippet of my code below... thanksss!!

```
      <form name="bm_table" action="getsounds.php" method="post">
    <table id="display_user_urls" >
        <?php
        $dir = dir('/upload_sounds');
        echo "<tr>
      <td><strong>Mp3 Files</strong></td>";
        echo "<td><strong>Add Selected Mp3 To Members Page</strong></td>
      </tr>";
        while(false !== ($file = $dir->read())){
            if($file != "." && $file !=".."){
                $file1 = basename($file,".mp3");
         echo "<tr>
             <td><a href=\"".$file1."\">".htmlspecialchars($file1)."</a></td>
             <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"add[]\"value=\"".$file1."\"/></td>
              </tr>";
            }
        }
        echo  "<input id=\"add_mp3\" type=\"submit\" name=\"add_submit\" value=\"Click Here To Add\"/>";
        $dir->close();
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

---

Below is the post method page "getsounds.php"

```
    $files = scandir("uploads\\admin_uploads\\upload_sounds\\{$_POST['add'][0]}");

    $source = "uploads\\admin_uploads\\upload_sounds\\";

    $destination = "new_uploads48\\";
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(in_array($file,array(".","..")))continue;
        if(copy($source.$file,$destination.$file)){
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: I get 2 warnings >> Warning: opendir(uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds\mymp3): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C: and >>>Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given..... Very weird, this script does make a new folder but its empty.. I want to put the file in that new folder from what was selected via the post method in the checkbox form...

Comment: sorry I forgot to follow you. Let me check your question.

Comment: it says 'no file or directory' please tell me what is your directory map? like htdocs or www and then a folder named 'project' etc.

Comment: @imsiso Im not to sure where my directory map is located, but this file is in my local root.. www   I guess a more simplified question would be.. is there a simple route to take to copy/move files from a form..??

Comment: what you mean? you are working on localhost right? so please give me the list of files and folders in `c:\wampp\www\yourproject` or `c:\xampp\htdocs\yourproject` cause I think 98% the problem is there. so just give me a tree of files and folders inside the project related to this issue (there is no need to put all files just files you are using and also the files where the html is in the posted pag,etc). the problem is in ` $dir = dir('/upload_sounds');` it tries to get the upload_sounds directory which is in your site root.

Comment: C:\wamp\www\MyProject\index\admin.php   .... this admin.php page has the html form where i want to select the files to be moved to.... the page that im sending the post method to once ive selected the files to be moved to is C:\wamp\www\MyProject\index\members.php  Hence the upload_sounds folder is within the main root:    C:\wamp\www\Myproject\index\uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds\

Comment: sorry for late reply. try one of these `$dir = dir('.\uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds');` , `$dir = dir('\Myproject\index\uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds');` ,  `$dir = dir('..\uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds');` I think its because your path is pointing to base and you should try relative path or true absolute path, please let me know the result.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late response. It worked !!!.. Just as you said, I was pointing to the base rather than pointing to the absolute path..thanks so much!!

Comment: your welcome. Now I'm going to put an answer for your question. please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says.

> Warning: opendir(uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds\mymp3): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in C: ...

So I think the problem is in the path you gave.

Try one of these.

`$dir = dir('.\uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds');` , `$dir = dir('\Myproject\index\uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds');` , `$dir = dir('..\uploads\admin_uploads\upload_sounds');`

I think its because your path is pointing to base and you should try relative path or true and correct absolute path.

Comment: you welcome, I that was one of problems I often face and if you are not using a framework you can write classes or functions to help you generate paths for html and php easy and without mistake.